# Master user can't connect to an existing database in Aurora MySQL - RDS

Tags: mysql, amazon-aurora, mysql-5.7

I have a set of databases as below

```
mysql> show databases;
+------------------------+
| Database               |
+------------------------+
| information_schema     |
| sys                    |
| system                 |
| test                   |
```

When I try to access 'test' database using the master user I'm getting below error

```
mysql> use information_schema;
Database changed
mysql>
mysql>
mysql> use test;
ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database 'test'
mysql>
```

Why is this error generating ?
MySQL Version 5.7

Comment: check user rights to access `test` table, or try with root user

Comment: @user1844933 user has all privs to test database  `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `test`.*`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue seems to be that the database was not properly created.

create database test;

Resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This does not strike me as a privilege issue. Otherwise, an error message should denote that as `ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user xx to database xxx`. It's more likely there is something wrong with the data file. To demonstrate, we can create a test database.

```
mysql> create database test_db;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> use test_db;
Database changed

-- delete the test_db database directory from OS terminal. e.g in linux shell, execute:
root@test# rm -rf /path_to_mysql_datadir/test_db

-- back to mysql cli
mysql> use test_db;
ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database 'test_db'
```

Please also note, if you directly copy a database from a remote host to your current server's mysql data directory, you are able to switch to the database, but you can not use its tables.

```
-- supposing we have just copied a database named db from remote server using scp

-- back to mysql cli
mysql> use db;
Database changed

mysql> show tables;
+-------------+
| Tables_in_db |
+-------------+
| p           |
+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from p;
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'db.p' doesn't exist
```

As you can see , in this case , as mysql server did not register the table of the remote copied database, querying the table returned an error.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to include this is a RDS, so we didn't delete the database from OS level